# How to make a custom json formatter for winston@3 logger?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I'm trying to make a custom json formatter for winston v3.

Here is a single file with demo:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require("winston")
const { combine, timestamp, prettyPrint } = format

const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(timestamp(), prettyPrint())
})

logger.add(new transports.Console())

logger.info("test message", { data: { a: 1, b: [1, 2, 3, 4], d: new Date() } })

try {
  throw new Error("I'm an error!")
} catch (err) {
  logger.error(err)
}
```

It prints:

```
{ data: { a: 1, b: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], d: 2018-07-21T08:59:27.958Z },
  level: 'info',
  message: 'test message',
  timestamp: '2018-07-21T08:59:27.959Z',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'info',
  [Symbol(splat)]:
   [ { data: { a: 1, b: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], d: 2018-07-21T08:59:27.958Z } } ] }
{ Error: I'm an error!
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/max7z/projects/test/t32__test__winston__pretty-print_symbol/index.js:13:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:596:3)
  level: 'error',
  timestamp: '2018-07-21T08:59:27.962Z',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'error' }
```

I'd like to have almost the same output, but without some fields: [Symbol(level)], [Symbol(splat)].

Is it possible to remove [Symbol] fields from `prettyPrint` formatter?

Or how can I make my own custom json formatter with error stacktrace like prettyPrint has?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested the sample with **winston v3.3.3** and added a custom formatter to stringify the `data` object:

```js
const winston = require('winston');

const myFormatter = winston.format((info) => {
  const {message} = info;

  if (info.data) {
    info.message = `${message} ${JSON.stringify(info.data)}`;
    delete info.data; // We added `data` to the message so we can delete it
  }
  
  return info;
})();

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    }),
    myFormatter,
    winston.format.simple(),
  ),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
  ],
});
```

I ran the commands from the question and got the desired output.

**Execution:**

```js
logger.info('test message', {data: {a: 1, b: [1, 2, 3, 4], d: new Date()}});

try {
  throw new Error(`I'm an error!`);
} catch (err) {
  logger.error(err);
}
```

**Output:**

> info: test message {"a":1,"b":[1,2,3,4],"d":"2020-09-09T09:41:22.525Z"} {"timestamp":"2020-09-09 11:41:22"}
>
> error: I'm an error! {"timestamp":"2020-09-09 11:41:22"}

The JSON object can be also printed with tabs and line breaks when using `winston.format.prettyPrint()` instead of `winston.format.simple()`.

Comment: shouldnt it be myFormatter() when inside the combine?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [how to create custom formats](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#creating-custom-formats).
Then use the [source code](https://github.com/winstonjs/logform/blob/master/pretty-print.js) of `prettyPrint` as a base to create a modified version based on your needs.

Winstons uses [`triple-beam`](https://github.com/winstonjs/triple-beam) for definitions for the various `Symbol`s, so you can also use that package to remove them.

Comment: Can you please give an example how to remove [Symbol] fields from `prettyPrint` output? I've read your links, but I still don't have any ideas how to do it.

Comment: You remove these fields just like any other field with `delete`.

Comment: I agree @max7z the docs are super confusing. I'm not using splat, but I keep seeing splat in some console.debug calls, and I can't seem to get a field added to the output in the format I want. For being the most used logger this thing is confusing as hell :(

Answer (score 3):

Refer [Winston format](http://info%5BSymbol.for(%22splat%22)%5D)

```
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, printf, prettyPrint, splat, simple } = format;
 

const myFormat = printf(info => {
    // you can get splat attribue here as info[Symbol.for("splat")]
    // if you custome splat please rem splat() into createLogger()
    return `${info.timestamp} [${info.label}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});

const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(
    label({ label: 'dicom-interactive.com' }),
    timestamp(),
    splat(),
    myFormat
  ),
  transports: [
      new transports.Console(),
      new transports.File({
        filename: "info.log",
        level: 'info'
      }),
      new transports.File({
        filename: "error.log",
        level: 'error'
      })
    ]
})
 
logger.info("test message %o", { data: { a: 1, b: [1, 2, 3, 4], d: new Date() } });

module.exports = logger;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered kind of same problem and found solution in [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/examples/metadata.js). I am using Node.js and Socket.IO,I've used logger in Socket.IO. As an example:

**Node.js**

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
  var date = new Date();
  socket.on('',function(data){
    logger.log('info', {IP: ip, Date: date, Path: '', Data: data.req_data});
```

**Winston.js**(logger)

```
const app_root = require('app-root-path');
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');


var logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format(function(info, opts){
        console.log(`[${info.IP}]-[${info.Date}]-[${info.Path}]-[${info.Data}]`);
        return info;
    })(),
    format.json()

  ),

  transports: [
    new transports.File({filename: `${app_root}/logs/info.log`})
  ]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

As much as I understand we can use random variables(ip,date,bird,ball, etc..) as we want. I think after little bit arrangment you can use this for errors too. Good luck!